# Multi-state survival analysis with mstate

Tags: r, survival-analysis

As a non-expert in survival analysis and or multi-state (Markov) models, I am seeking advice on an approach to applying both of these in combination.

I am interested in a multi-stage training process. Successful students need to pass through a number of strictly sequential training units, say states A, B and C. If and when they successfully complete state A, they move immediately on to state B, etc. Students may fail and exit the process from any state until successfully completing C. Substantial historical data is available on transition times between states: Commence A to transition A/B; Transition A/B to transition B/C; Commence A to fail A; etc. On any given day, there will be students in each active state. For all of these students, my question is how to estimate the probability that they will complete state C within a specified future time window. I am content to consider all students as identical for now, characterised only by their durations in each previous state and their censored duration in the current state at the time of the forecast.

My current thinking is to use the mstate package in R with competing risks and a clock-forward approach. For the predictions, I would then set "predt" in the subsequent call to probtrans as (time of the forecast - time of commencement of state A) and then access the list item in the probtrans output for the student's current state from which the probability of completing state C at future times may be read.

Does this seem like a sensible approach and if so, am I interpreting the output correctly. Alternatively, is there some other superior method of which I should be aware.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: This question is probably best suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Will resubmit there.